# What use for app with connection db even background

Tags: android

this Is my First app android.

I've read documentation for develop an app with db connection wit rest service and I chose Volley service for comunicate app with rest service that I've created.

Now i've doubts.
I have To connect my app with my db, and as long as my app Is "active" I've no problem because I could create a Singleton that performance all operation with my db, but I need To connect my db even with service in background, and so i would use same function for background service and even when my app Is open.
I read that Singleton, when my app close, could be destroy and so context for cachedir network that need volley.

So what i should use for a request even app active and background service?

Comment: if you are using a background service then your app does not "close" it stays "open"

Comment: So this singleton that I've create should be a service? And if i want call my service method on activity after startService(i) how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) if you'd like to do some long running job when app is not visible for user.

Comment: Thankyou, So i've startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification); and after start how can i call a method on my service?
I'm in my main activity and I start my foreground service, in my service I'have a method getData(){} with call a db and return Jsonobject so I

start service, and for call a getData and assign to variable in my activity?

Comment: @LorenzoBerti You can't call methods in service directly from Activity. You should send an Intents to that service, and service, when will receive that intents will already do certain job. Please try to read more tutorials.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti if that answer, answers your question, you should mark it.